# Spark Executor logs in local or standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am running spark submit job in my local environment and to debug the whole process want to see the executor logs. For this I have made following changes :-

1. Editing the log4j property file - 2 property files, one each for executor and one for driver

   ```
   log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, file
   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/executor-application.log
   log4j.appender.file.append=false
   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
   ```

2- Adding the log details into **spark-default.conf** file

```
 spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/spark-setup/conf/log4j-executor.properties
 spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/spark-setup/conf/log4j-driver.properties
```

When I run the spark-submit job locally, I see only the driver logs not the executor log.

```
spark-submit --master "local[*]" --class com.test.action.myjob test_job.jar
```

Am I missing something ?? why I can't see the executor logs ??
Any pointers will help.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Configure logging options:**

You may need to [configure logging options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkLogging.html#sparkLogging__sparkLogginglog-configuration-file-2spIHjOa) for executors in `logback-spark-executor.xml`.

**Potentially add settings for rolling executor logging:**
You may want to add some configuration settings in `spark-daemon-defaults.conf` if you want [rolling executor logging](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkLogging.html).

**Runtime variables:**
Note that there are some [RTE (runtime) variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) related to the executor logs that can be set.